# pass managedObjectContext through NavigatioController and TableView to CustomViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to pass my managedObjectContext from the AppDelegate to a certain view controller.

My setup in storyboard looks like this:

[image: storyboard setup]

And I want to be able to access the managedObjectContext from the selected Custom View Controller.

So far I have in the AppDelegate.m:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
CustomScrollViewController *controller = (CustomScrollViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

which I took from the MasterDetail project.

However, this doesn't work, probably because it doesn't account for the Table View Controller in between. How can I change the code to fit my needs? I have already searched for this, but I'm too new to this to be able to tailor other's answers to my needs.

By the way, this is the corresponding github repository: https://github.com/frederike/NZTravellerApp/tree/master/NZTravellerApp

Comment: I can't see CustomScrollViewController.h/.m in the github repository. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a property to hold the context on your Table View Controller, then pass it onto your `CustomScrollViewController`.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setContext:self.context];
}
```

Alternativly in your `CustomScrollViewController`...

```
self.context = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: As for the first suggestion: I would then still need to pass the context from Navigation controller to Table View Controller. Would my code above be ok if I replace the customscrollVC with the tableVC? Also, so far my table view controller only exists in the storyboard and I am unsure how to add code to it (sorry, I'm quite new to this and always confused when it comes to communicating between code and storyboard). as for the second option: people with similar problems always got told that it was "bad form"... 
I also added my github repository to the OP, to show what I have so far.

Comment: Yes your code above would be fine if you switch the tableVC and customscrollVC. To "add code" to a view controller you should create a subclass of UIViewController/UITableViewController and change the class of the VC in the storyboard.

Comment: I just changed created a subclass and set it as the class for my table view controller, but now the two items that I added via storyboard in the original tableVC (see above) don't show up when I start the app. Without adding them again programmatically to the new subclass, how can I make them show up?

Comment: UITableViewController uses dynamic cells by default. You should really read the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! Using your first suggestion, I now ran into another problem, for which I have submitted a second question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831394/passing-managedobjectcontext-via-prepareforsegue
Maybe you could take a look?