# passing ManagedObjectContext via prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, nsmanagedobjectcontext

First of all, [this is my basic setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg6W1.jpg).
I'm trying to pass a NSManagedObjectContext (MOC) from my AppDelegate to the selected custom ViewController.

First, in "AppDelegate.m", I do:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
FirstTableViewController *tableVC = (FirstTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
tableVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

to pass the MOC to the tableViewController which is in between the navigationController and the custom ViewController.

This causes no errors so far.

However, in the tableViewController "FirstTableViewController.m", I then want to pass the MOC onto the custom ViewController using prepareforsegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mapClicked"]) {
        CustomScrollViewController *customSVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

        [customSVC setManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
}
```

This then calls the following method in the custom ViewController "CustomScrollViewController.m":

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self.managedObjectContext = context;
}
```

and this is where it gets stuck. It seems to perform the method over and over again, ( [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqA5W.jpg) ) and then crashes.

If you need to look at more code, [here is the github repository](https://github.com/frederike/NZTravellerApp/tree/master/NZTravellerApp)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need the custom setter method `setManagedObjectContext` at all,
because property accessor methods are created automatically by the compiler, if necessary.

But if you use a custom setter, it must access the instance variable directly
inside the setter:

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    _managedObjectContext = context;
}
```

The reason is that

```
self.managedObjectContext = context;
```

is translated by the compiler to

```
[self setManagedObjectContext:context];
```

and there you have the recursion.

Comment: Oh, I see! Now, when I write _managedObjectContext I get asked if I mean managedObjectContext. Is there a reason why I shoudl use the underscore before? And do I put the underscore already in the property declaration
(AT)property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
or only before the synthesize
(AT)synthesize managedObjectContext;
or before both?

Comment: @freda42: `@synthesize managedObjectContext;` is equivalent to `@synthesize managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;`, so that the ivar is created without the leading underscore. - With the current compilers, you can just *omit the synthesize completely*. Then the compiler will automatically insert `@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;`, so that the ivar is create with a leading underscore. This is the currently recommended style, so that you can distinguish between properties and ivars easily. And don't put the leading underscore into the property declaration!

Answer (score 1):

This code contains your problem:

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self.managedObjectContext = context;
}
```

You should simply synthesize your properties. This code will in fact result in this:

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    [self setManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

So you se the recursion? So either synthesise, or, if you really want to implement this yourself: (I am assuming you use ARC, and that there is an instance variable called _context.

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Also, if you are implementing you own getter, this should be it:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{
    return _context;
}
```